# Can generate an address by mnemonic with the sdk substrate-interface?

Tags: polkadot, parachain, kusama, python, substrateinterface

I want to generate an kusama address. The substrate-interface can make it?Or how to generate an ss58 format address by python

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the SS58 prefix to the `create_from_mnemonic` function to make it generate a Kusama address as opposed to a generic Substrate address:

```python
from substrateinterface import Keypair

# 2 for Kusama.
prefix = 2
# If you want to use a random mnemonic:
mnemonic = Keypair.generate_mnemonic()
# ... or use a specific mnemonic:
mnemonic = 'episode together nose spoon dose oil faculty zoo ankle evoke admit walnut'

keypair = Keypair.create_from_mnemonic(mnemonic, ss58_format=prefix)
# Prints JHXFqYWQFFr5RkHVzviRiKhY7tutyGcYQb6kUyoScSir862
print(keypair.ss58_address)
```

Kusama has the prefix 2, you can see all of them in the [ss58-registry](https://github.com/paritytech/ss58-registry/blob/main/ss58-registry.json).

Comment: Also you can add `Keypair.generate_mnemonic()` to the anwser above to generate a new address

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate you answering the Python questions!